# flotr2 - hover on line in line chart

Tags: javascript, graph, hover, flotr2

I"m using plugin "flotr2" to display a line chart in my app.

I have to display a tooltip when I hover on points and another tooltip when i hover on the line.

I use in "track" parameter at "mouse" field in the options.
I saw there is anoter parameter call "trackAll". 
It was not good for me,becasue it show all the time a tooltip and not just when I was on the line.

here is my code:

```
dataArray.push({
        data: createDataObject(data),
        lines: {
            fill: true,
            show: true,
            fillOpacity: 0.1
        },
        points: {
            show: true,
            fillOpacity: '0',
            radius: 2,
            lineWidth: 2
        },
        mouse: {
            data: data,
            track: true,
            position: 'n',
            relative: true,
            trackFormatter: function (obj) {                    
                return setTooltipData(data, obj);                    
            }, // => formats the values in the value box
            margin: 7, // => margin in pixels of the valuebox
            lineColor: '#FFFFFFFF', // => line color of points that are drawn when mouse comes near a value of a series
            trackDecimals: 1, // => decimals for the track values
            sensibility: 3, // => the lower this number, the more precise you have to aim to show a value //hover area 
            trackY: true, // => whether or not to track the mouse in the y axis
            radius: 2, // => radius of the track point
            lineWidth: 2,
            fillColor: null, // => color to fill our select bar with only applies to bar and similar graphs (only bars for now)
            fillOpacity: 1 // => opacity of the fill color, set to 1 for a solid fill, 0 hides the fill 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "track:!0,trackAll:!1" to mouse.